# Шаблонное наследование в Python

Tags: python, шаблоны

Помогите пожалуйста с следующим вопросом.

Мне очень надо на Python реализовать следующую схему по сути являющуюся аналогом шаблонного наследования в С++.

Есть базовый класс `A(object)`. От него могут наследоваться классы `B1(A)`, `B2(A)`, `B3(A)` и так далее.

Потом надо отнаследовать от них единообразным способом класс `С`. Можно, конечно, просто передать класс `Bi` в `С` просто как значение поля, но намного более элегантным и консистентным с имеющейся базой кода будет вариант при котором `С` будет унаследован от `Bi` и последний будет инициализирован при инициализации С аналогично стандартной процедуре с `super(C, self).\__init__()`.

Спасибо

Comment: Рєймонд Хєттингер в помощь:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=61UuKJRl2m0
а то мне в вопросе примера не хватает )

Comment: возможно вам нужна страницы 37 и 139 книги Марка Самммерфилда "Python на практике"?

Comment: приведите код - что у вас получилось что нет, в чем проблема. Просто напишите пример с "полупустыми" классами... Python c его "утиным" и "гусиным" наследованием намного проще шаблонных шаблонов шаблонного проектирования

Comment: что вы понимаете под "шаблонным наследованием в Python". В Питоне нет шаблонов. Что значит "унаследовать единобрачным способом"? Вы хотите чтобы C наследовал сразу от всех B1,B2,B3 классов? (множественное наследование) В чём проблема? Зачем это нужно?

Comment: можно глянуть здесь: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Шаблонный_метод_(шаблон_проектирования)

Comment: Возможно, у вас все  в порядке и сложность задачи требует совместного применения паттернов "шаблон" и "мост"?
Приведите ваш код или можно продолжить общение на основе приведенного ниже кода из википедии.

Comment: если вы не можете объяснить, что вы понимаете под *"шаблонным наследованием в Python"*, тогда приведите минимальный пример кода на С++, который вы хотите на Питоне эмулировать. Возможно всё гораздо проще в Питоне, к примеру, `def makeC(B): class C(B): pass \n return C`

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, вас удовлетворит [ответ из википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)), там можно открыть спойлер с примером на Пайтоне в том числе.

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod


class Unit(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    """
    Абстрактный отряд. Аттрибуты класса, начинающиеся с подчеркивания в python
    являются protected
    """
def __init__(self, speed: int) -> None:
    """
    Constructor.

    :param speed: скорость отряда
    """
    self._speed = speed

def hit_and_run(self) -> None:
    """
    Шаблонный метод
    """
    self._move('вперед')
    self._stop()
    self._attack()
    self._move('назад')

@abstractmethod
def _attack(self) -> None:
    pass

@abstractmethod
def _stop(self) -> None:
    pass

def _move(self, direction: str) -> None:
    """
    Передвижение - у всех отрядов одинаковое, в шаблон не входит

    :param direction: направление движения
    """
    self._output('движется {} со скоростью {}'.format(direction, self._speed))

def _output(self, message: str) -> None:
    """
    Вспомогательный метод вывода сообщений, в шаблон не входит

    :param message: выводимое сообщение
    """
    print('Отряд типа {} {}'.format(self.__class__.__name__, message))


class Archers(Unit):
    """
    Лучники
    """
def _attack(self) -> None:
    self._output('обстреливает врага')

def _stop(self) -> None:
    self._output('останавливается в 100 шагах от врага')


class Cavarlymen(Unit):
    """
    Кавалеристы
    """
def _attack(self) -> None:
    self._output('на полном скаку врезается во вражеский строй')

def _stop(self) -> None:
    self._output('летит вперед, не останавливаясь')

#### два класса добавил к разговору о детализации вашей проблемы. Что надо-то получить?

class Kentavr(Archers, Cavarlymen):
    pass

class ArmoredCavarlymen(Cavarlymen):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('OUTPUT:')
    archers = Archers(4)
    archers.hit_and_run()
    cavarlymen = Cavarlymen(8)
    cavarlymen.hit_and_run()

'''

OUTPUT:
Отряд типа Archers движется вперед со скоростью 4
Отряд типа Archers останавливается в 100 шагах от врага
Отряд типа Archers обстреливает врага
Отряд типа Archers движется назад со скоростью 4
Отряд типа Cavarlymen движется вперед со скоростью 8
Отряд типа Cavarlymen летит вперед, не останавливаясь
Отряд типа Cavarlymen на полном скаку врезается во вражеский строй
Отряд типа Cavarlymen движется назад со скоростью 8
'''
```